# Unable to run Algolia Docsearch in my docusaurus v2 website

Tags: algolia, docusaurus, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

I have received my algolia `apiKey` and the `indexName`, I have correctly added them under `themeConfig` in my `docusauras.config.js` file

```
algolia: {
      apiKey: 'API_KEY',
      indexName: 'INDEX_NAME',
    },
```

However, my docsearch is not working. I have applied for docsearch via the free tier. 
As per Docusauras [docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/search) I need to add only the `apiKey` and `indexName` received to get it working which I did but it's not working.(**only the loading indicator appears nothing else**). **Please Help**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running my site locally after integrating the docsearch(**I didn't push the changes to my live website, silly I know**). It seems algolia was unable to crawl my site hosted on the local server(**obviously because crawler was configured to run on my domain provided**). However, pushing the changes live solved the issue.

> *Don't forget to push the changes live after integrating algolia.*